# Error: use of overloaded operator '[]' is ambiguous while building for i386

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, x86-64, clang++, i386

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

class test_class
{
public:
    test_class() {}
    ~test_class() {}

    const int32_t operator[](uint32_t index) const
    {
        return (int32_t)index;
    }

    operator const char *() const
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    test_class tmp;
    printf("%d\n", tmp[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

When I use command `clang++ -arch i386 test.cc` to build those codes, it yields the following on clang++ (Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.1)):

```
test.cc:24:21: error: use of overloaded operator '[]' is ambiguous (with operand types 'test_class' and 'int')
  printf("%d\n", tmp[3]);
                 ~~~^~
test.cc:10:17: note: candidate function
  const int32_t operator[](uint32_t index) const
                ^
test.cc:24:21: note: built-in candidate operator[](const char *, int)
  printf("%d\n", tmp[3]);
                    ^
test.cc:24:21: note: built-in candidate operator[](const volatile char *, int)
```

But there is no error if I just use command `clang++ test.cc`

It seems that overloading operator '[]' on i386 is different from on x86_64 and I want to know what the exactly distinction is.

Comment: Don't know why there is a difference in the 2 builds.  But the reason for the fail with the i386 build is that the compiler can use the user supplied conversion operator then index the char array, or just index the variable.

Comment: @RichardCritten, to call the overload `operator[](char *,int)` the first argument is constructed by a user defined conversion so it shall have a lower rank than other overload. I can not reproduce it but it looks like a clang bug.

Comment: @Oliv  Using `g++ -m32 test.cc` produces "warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second", and the version of g++ is (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3) 7.2.0 . But clang takes it as an error.

Comment: There is always scope for ambiguity when a class provides both an `operator[]()` that accepts an integral argument, as well as a conversion to any type that supports array syntax (either a pointer, or a type with its own `operator[]()`.   Rough rule of thumb:  either provide an `operator[]()` or provide a conversion to a pointer type, not both.     Also, regardless of how the ambiguity might be resolved, the `printf("%d", tmp[3])` gives undefined behaviour, since neither possibility gives a result of type `int`.

Comment: @Peter, What confused me is why there is no error or warning when building those codes with x86_64.

Comment: Be not surprised. When specific integer types like `int32_t` enter into the code, size matters.  Whether or not a compiler should issue a warning in this case when compiling for x64 is debatable.

Comment: @NinetyPercent - because, on different builds, `int32_t` may be the same size, but basic types like `int` (including the literal `3`) differ in size.   That affects the rank of integral types (in your case) and that, in turn, affects whether a call of an `operator[]()` function is preferred over a type conversion operator.   So what works with one build may not work with another.  That is also why recent standards say these things are ambiguous - since there is variation between implementations [different builds amount to using different implementations, say a 32-bit vs a 64-bit compiler].

Comment: My mistake sorry, to be a best overload, all conversion for each arguments (included the implicit object) must be a *not worst conversion sequence* than the other. Here int to unint32_t, is an *integral convertion* and has *conversion rank*... Borring overloading. You could solve it by providing an other overload for [] taking an int as index.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible interpretations of `tmp[3]`: the "obvious" one, calling `test_class::operator[](int32_t)`, and the less obvious one, calling `test_class::operator const char*()` to convert the object to a `const char*`, and applying the index to that pointer.

To decide which of the overloads to use, the compiler looks at the conversions involved. There are two arguments for each overload: `tmp` and `3`. For the first overload, `tmp` needs no conversion, but `3` has to be converted from `int` to `int32_t`. For the second overload, `tmp` needs to be converted to `const char*`, and `3` does not have to be converted.

To choose the proper overload, the compiler has to look at the conversion set for each argument. For the first argument, `tmp`, the first overload requires no conversion, and the second requires an integral conversion. So the first overload wins here. For the second argument, the first overload requires a user-defined conversion and the second requires no conversion. So the first conversion wins.

In short: the first overload wins on the first argument, and the second overload wins on the second argument. So the call is ambiguous.

You could add an overloaded `operator[](int)`, which would resolve this particular complaint, but it would be an error with a compiler where `int32_t` is a synonym for `int`.

Your best bet is probably to get rid of `operator[](int32_t)` and replace it with `operator[](int)`.

This is why you have to think carefully about fixed-size types: you can get conversions that you aren't expecting.